# How can I import example project inside of pub-get packages in flutter

Tags: flutter

Some of pub-get packages have example project inside of the project.

and I search for how to import example project.

most of answer is add path:../

but that doesn't work for me

```
camerawesome:
    path: ../
```

makes error : Can't find the pubspec.yaml file in /Users/user_name/workspace/flutter-workspace

How can I import example project

flutter create example and copy the source is the only way?

example source looks like import using underbar directory, this is also not make sense for me.

import 'package:camerawesome_example/widgets/top_bar.dart';

Thanks for read my question !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want import example code to your project, just like a third lib ?

the example project not real part of lib. you cant just import the code to

your code for use. it's not design for that. it's just show how to use lib.